# Side-effects (unexpected/unwanted) of changing the "default" SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, insufficient-memory, huawei

In have a Huawei phone that came with 32GB. If I add a new bigger SD card what are the implications?
I mean would my installed applications be affected/disappear? Would any configuration any app change/break? Or does it affect only files saved? Not sure if that affects or how the internal storage

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129902/discussion-on-question-by-jim-side-effects-unexpected-unwanted-of-changing-the).

Answer (score 1):

[adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) won't work for Android 7.0-8.1 with FBE encryption, therefore nothing will happen to apps.

portable storage allows you to remove MicroSD Card off the device and read data from PC card reader without data loss. If however for some reason windows is not able to detect file system, do **not** format MicroSD Card if windows ask for it. Instead read MicroSD Card from linux.

If you insert MicroSD Card back into device files will be available as before

Comment: Which is the PC card reader e.g. in the Windows? Is it something I need to buy?

Comment: I suppose something like this is the same? https://www.amazon.com/Anker-Portable-Reader-RS-MMC-Micro/dp/B006T9B6R2/ref=sr_1_3?_encoding=UTF8&c=ts&dchild=1&keywords=Computer+Memory+Card+Readers